# How to Split the value and find the longest text string in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, split, conditional-formatting

I have a column in google sheet in which each cell contains this type of text

```
manager, finance manager
accountant
accountant, chief accountant
manager, auditor, other, finance manager
accountant
```

I want to find the longest text like below and show that text into new cell

```
finance manager
accountant
chief accountant
finance manager
accountant
```

I used split function to split the text and find function but finding character or number of character is working but i am unable to understand how i will get whole longest word

Kindly help me.

Comment: Do you wish a script or a formula?

Comment: any solution is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use

```
=FILTER(TRIM(SPLIT(A1, ",")), LEN(SPLIT(A1, ",")) = MAX(LEN(SPLIT(A1, ","))))
```

and fill down as far as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your comma-separated lists reside in A2:A. Place the following in, say, B2 of an otherwise empty range B2:B ...

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"[^,]{"&REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"[^,]{"&SEQUENCE(1,30,30,-1)&"}")=FALSE,,SEQUENCE(1,30,30,-1))),,30))),"\S+")*1&"}"))))`

This is a complex formula, one that would be difficult to explain. So I will leave it to you (and others who may be interested) to dissect, analyze and understand the inner workings. However, if there is a specific question I can answer should you (or others) get stuck, feel free to ask.

In short, the formula checks to see if there are any REGEX matches for non-comma groupings of 30 characters in length, then 29, 28 and so on to 1. If so, that number is returned in a space-separated list. The first number (which will be the highest) is returned and used to extract a non-comma REGEX expression of that exact length (which then has any leading or trailing spaces removed from it).

Comment: above script is also working correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your text is stored in column A, you can use this formula:

```
=hlookup(max(arrayformula(len(trim(split(A1,","))))), {arrayformula(len(trim(split(A1,","))));arrayformula(trim(split(A1,",")))},2,False)
```

Second option is to write a custom function.